# Veracity of callback protocol

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

```py
from typing import Callable, Protocol


def caller_callable(fn: Callable[[int], str]):
    fn(1)


class Callback(Protocol):

    def __call__(self, x: int) -> str:
        pass


def caller_callback(fn: Callback):
    fn(1)


caller_callable(object)  # fail
caller_callback(object)  # pass

caller_callable(lambda x: x)  # fail
caller_callback(lambda x: x)  # pass

caller_callable(lambda x: int(x))  # fail
caller_callback(lambda x: int(x))  # fail

caller_callable(lambda x: str(x))  # pass
caller_callback(lambda x: str(x))  # pass
```

I'm using mypy 0.971.
I've been treating the callback protocol as more feature rich version of Callable type. However, it seems that callback protocol allows invalid invocations that are not permitted by `Callback`. Is that expected? In the documentation (https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#callback-protocols) I see:

> Callback protocols and Callable[...] types can be used interchangeably.

That would suggest to me that I am either misspecifying the protocol, mypy is incorrect, or there's another option that eludes me.

Comment: I reckon this might be a bug in how mypy infers the type of `lambda`s